# Why Application insight is not working after doing slot swapping in azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using application insight for measuring performance and also storing some telemetry data of my web application and it was working fine till last month.

But from last month I am unable to see any traffic in app insight. In last month just I have added one slot in my app service. I have checked instrumentation key, it's same and correct and there is no change in application settings and configuration in app service.

Could you please suggest me if any additional settings I need to take care ?

I suspect this issue is due to adding of slot because in other environment it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you enabling application insights for the App in Azure Web App? Are you using extensions or do you take nuget dependency at build time?
If using extension, please navigate to this url to find the status of application insights enablement: https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/ApplicationInsights

Have you ensured that that instrumentation key is available in all slots? This is most likely an instrumentation key issue.

Comment: @cijthomas- I am using SDK for it. I have tried by putting instrumentation key in both the slots and also I putted same web.config.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Can you collect SDK logs by sending them to a file? instructions are here.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#troubleshooting-logs

Comment: @cijothomas- I'll try by logging the SDK logs, meanwhile I have noticed that applicationInsight.owinextension is being implemented in our code... Is it issue with it? but same code was working fine earlier 2 months...

Comment: Thanks all. Issue has been resolved.. because of some BIN folder DLLs is not getting published via VSTS therefore application insight is not working. Now, I have published directly through visual studio and it's started working.

Answer (score 2):

You could go to Visual Studio configure Application Insights through there and then redeploy the application to slot.

For more information, you could refer to this doc: [Application Insights support for Multiple Environments, Stamps and App Versions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/), , specifically the 'Multi Stamp Support'.

Comment: Should I deploy on secondary slot and then swap? It's working fine for other environment where slot is not created.

Comment: @Ajay, just deploy to the slot you want, you could configure your settings.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, really appreciate. But could you please confirm what kind of configuration should I do for slotting to re-enable the app insight? I never faced this type of issue earlier.

Comment: @Ajay, I test it doesn't need much configurations, it just need enable the Application Insights then it will add the settings automatically. So did you add the setting manually or just enable the Application Insights?

Comment: I tried with both options 1. Enabling the application insight using extension 2. Enabled the application insight using instrumentations key. But unfortunately no traffic is getting captured.